# Access iPhone filesystem without plugging in the device?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, macos, filesystems

Is there a way I can access the iphone root filesystem via xcode? I really don't care how malicious it is, but I just want to test a few things on my device.

Mostly so I can replace the default boot image to my own.

Thank you,

All responses are appreciated

Answer (score 0):

No. Normally, filesystem access is limited to the sandbox in which your application lives. It doesn't matter if the device is tethered or not.

The only way to get full filesystem access is to jailbreak your device. In that case, you can install OpenSSH and have full untethered access to the filesystem and/or run unsigned code on the device and do whatever you want.

Comment: So I wouldn't be able to replace the boot image file with one a user selects just through an application run on a non-jailbroken device? How could I access it through OpenSSH if it was targeted for jailbroken devices?

Comment: @TwoDumpling Oh, I assumed you wanted to do this to your own device, over Wi-Fi. If you want to create an app that changes the boot image, then I guess you won't need OpenSSH, just a jailbroken device.

Comment: Yes not over wifi, just run it on my own jailbroken device.